# Applying functions w.r.t. calendar days in R

Tags: r, dataframe, calendar, apply, covariance

I have daily (financial) time series. As every month does not end in the 30th or 31st, it has created problems for myself using `apply` functions. Using monthly time series I can just specify every `n'th` month. However, how can I specify every `n'th` month with daily series.

Let's say I have this date data set:

```
dates <- seq(as.Date("2000-01-01"), length = 1000, by = "days")

data <- cbind(rnorm(1000, mean = 0.01, sd = 0.001),
              rnorm(1000, mean = 0.01, sd = 0.001),
              rnorm(1000, mean = 0.01, sd = 0.001))
```

Particularly, I want to run covariance matrices for every `n'th` month similarly to:

```
cov.fixed <- lapply(as.data.frame(t(rollapply(1:nrow(data), 90, c))),
 function(i) cov(data[i,]))
```

But instead of `90` is it possible to write as every `3rd month` such that it takes into account the calendar days?

Many thanks

Comment: See package `zoo` functions `as.yearmon` and `as.yearqtr`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @RuiBarradas, but I struggle to see how can I `apply` every n'th month with `as.yearmon`. Any directions would be very helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the covariances every month, you can do something like the following. The key is to `split` the matrix by `month`.

```
library(zoo)

month <- as.yearmon(dates)

cov.month <- lapply(split(as.data.frame(data), month), cov)

names(cov.month) <- sub(" ", "_", names(cov.month))
cov.month$Jan_2000
#             V1           V2           V3
#V1 7.825062e-07 7.063689e-08 9.561721e-08
#V2 7.063689e-08 8.989207e-07 1.293351e-07
#V3 9.561721e-08 1.293351e-07 1.175318e-06

cov.month[[1]]    # The same
```

As for quarters, the code is similar, just substitute `as.yearqtr` for `as.yearmon`.

```
quarter <- as.yearqtr(dates)
cov.quarter <- lapply(split(as.data.frame(data), quarter), cov)
```

Then make better names, without spaces, with `sub` like above.

**Data.**

Unlike in the question, I have set the RNG seed.

```
set.seed(3658)    # Make the results reproducible
data <- cbind(rnorm(1000, mean = 0.01, sd = 0.001),
              rnorm(1000, mean = 0.01, sd = 0.001),
              rnorm(1000, mean = 0.01, sd = 0.001))
```

Comment: Is it also possible to do this with rolling windows? For example that `cov.quarter[[1]]` is for the `2000-01-01` to `2000-03-01`, `cov.quarter[[2]]` is for `2000-01-02` to `2000-03-02` etc.?